# Member access within null pointer of type 'ListNode'

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I had a runtime error:

```
member access within null pointer of type 'ListNode'.
at the line (current_3->val = digit;)
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:33:24
```

I don't know what this error means. Could you explain the problem and how I can solve it, please?

```cpp
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        int carry = 0;
        int sum, digit=0;
        ListNode l3;
        ListNode *current_1 = l1->next;
        ListNode *current_2 = l2->next;
        ListNode *current_3 = l3.next;
        while (current_1 != NULL && current_2 != NULL) {
            sum = current_1->val + current_2->val + carry;
            digit = sum % 10;
            carry = sum / 10;
            current_3->val = digit;
            current_1 = current_1->next;
            current_2 = current_2->next;
            current_3 = current_3->next;
        }
        return &l3;
    }
};
```

Comment: `while (current_1 != NULL && current_2 != NULL) ` what happens when `current3 == NULL` ?

Comment: it is  `NULL` right from the start. Here `ListNode *current_3 = l3.next;` and then you dereference that nullptr: `current_3->val`.

Comment: leetcode (or other coding challenges) will not teach you basics of the language. They assume you already know them

Comment: you should learn how to use a debugger

Comment: `current_3` is null (which should be clear if you follow the code) so `current_3->val` is an error. You are trying to create a new list of nodes to return the sum. So you need to **allocate** those nodes using `new`. You don't get them by magic.

Comment: A note about using the debugger: you'll also need an input set that exposes the mistake, and online judges rarely expose the input to you. You need to make a tester and discover input sets that test all of the cases. Sometimes when you're really stuck finding failure cases you'll have to fall back on [fuzzing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you might do this. I haven't seen the original problem, so this might not be correct, however it does allocate the nodes for the list correctly.

```
ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
    int carry = 0;
    ListNode* head = NULL;
    ListNode* tail = NULL;
    while (l1 != NULL && l2 != NULL) {
        int sum = l1->val + l2->val + carry;
        int digit = sum % 10;
        carry = sum / 10;
        ListNode* tmp = new ListNode(digit); // allocate a new node
        if (head == NULL)                    // if the list is empty
            head = tmp;                      // then head points to the new node
        else
            tail->next = tmp;                // otherwise add to the end of the list
        tail = tmp;                          // tail points to the new end of the list
        l1 = l1->next;
        l2 = l2->next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Notice how each digit added to the list has a node allocated with `new ListNode(digit)`. The `head` variable points to the beginning of the list, and the `tail` variable points to the last node in the list, allowing you to efficiently add new nodes to the end of the list. This is a classic way of building a linked list.